# Likelihood of two dependent variables

Tags: probability, machine-learning

If $Z\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $X$ is an indicator variable s.t. $X=1\iff Z\ge t$ for a given $t\ge 0$, I'm trying to find the likelihood $p(X,Z|\lambda)$.

My calculations were: $p(x,z|\lambda)=p(x|z,\lambda)p(z|\lambda)=e^{-\lambda tx}(1-e^{-\lambda t})^{1-x}p(z|\lambda)=e^{-\lambda tx}(1-e^{-\lambda t})^{1-x}\lambda e^{-\lambda z}$.

However, the solution claims that it is : $p(x,z|\lambda)=\lambda e^{-\lambda z}$

Is this because X is dependent on Z? Which mistake am I making?

Comment: If you know the value of $Z$ then knowing $X$ gives you no additional information about $\lambda$, and so does not affect the likelihood of $\lambda$ given $X$ and $Z$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I understand it intuitively, but would there be a mathematical explanation as to why is that the case? Is there a term for variables in such cases?  I still don't see where I made the mistake in the calculation despite understanding your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your $p(x\mid z,\lambda)=e^{-\lambda tx}(1-e^{-\lambda t})^{1-x}$ is wrong.

It should not depend on $\lambda$ ($X$ is determined by $Z$ and $t$) and should be $1$ in any possible case $(x=1, z\ge t$ or $x=0,z<t)$ and $0$ otherwise.

This means that in any possible case, if you know the value of $Z$ then knowing $X$ gives you no additional information about $λ$, and so $X$ does not affect the likelihood of $λ$ given $X$ and $Z$.  Thus the likelihood of $\lambda$ is proportional to $\lambda e^{-\lambda z}$